# How to split csv column value using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, azure-powershell, powershell-remoting

I have a csv columns that have multiple columns and I need to split a particular column called "Path" that look something like this

```
SharePoint\user\Documents\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\Audit-Log-Script\.git\objects\ff\76e4656b4e0afa14ad3a6ea03fb6d40a5bb7c0
SharePoint\user\Documents\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\Audit-Log-Script\Data\User_v512.csv
```

I'm just wondering how can I use the last backlash symbol for indicator. If there is a dot after the last backlash then it's a "File" if there no dot then, it's a "Folder"

I'm trying to for loop each row, create a new column called "Type" that will store "File" and "Folder" value and export it to the new csv file.

I'm stuck so any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
$Result=
foreach($CSVLine in $CSVImport){
    $CSVLine | 
        Select-Object -Property *,
            @{
                Name = 'Type'; 
           # Not sure how to do if else statement here to pass either "File" or "Folder" value
                Expression = {($_.Path -split "\")[-2]} \
            }
}
$Result |
    Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Personally, considering you have access to these paths and they actually exist, would use just `[IO.File]::GetAttributes(....)` to determine if they're a file or folder

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon  Sadly, I don't have the access. :(

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "If there is a dot after the last backlash then it's a "File" if there no dot then, it's a "Folder"? Looking at your example paths, both don't have a dot after the last backslash, so they would be folders? I think you should be looking at if the path has an extension or not, might be a better way to determine this

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon so the first path does not have a dot after the last backslash so that is a folder. The second path have a dot after the last backslash so that's a file.

Comment: Oh you mean the leaf has a dot haha yeah maybe I was looking at it literally. So basically, if the path has an extension

Comment: You are right. Basically I want to check if the path have extension or not. I'm not sure how to do that because The CSV file contains many different extensions type also that's why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Path` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path?view=net-6.0) can help you determine if the path has an extension or not using it's [`GetExtension` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=net-6.0). Using both paths provided in your question as an example:

```bash
@'
Path
SharePoint\user\Documents\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\Audit-Log-Script\.git\objects\ff\76e4656b4e0afa14ad3a6ea03fb6d40a5bb7c0
SharePoint\user\Documents\Desktop\PowerShell Scripts\Audit-Log-Script\Data\User_v512.csv
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | Select-Object @{
    Name       = 'Type'
    Expression = { if([IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Path)) { return 'File' } 'Directory' }
}, Path
```

The final code would be:

```bash
Import-Csv path\to\myCsv.csv | Select-Object @{
    Name       = 'Type'
    Expression = { if([IO.Path]::GetExtension($_.Path)) { return 'File' } 'Directory' }
}, Path | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

As [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) notes in his helpful comment, [`Split-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7) includes the [`-Extension` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/split-path?view=powershell-7#-extension) on [**PowerShell Core 7+**](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell):

```bash
Import-Csv .\test.csv  | Select-Object @{
    Name       = 'Type'
    Expression = { if(Split-Path -Extension $_.Path) { return 'File' } 'Directory' }
}, Path
```